# yii2 kartik select2 widget doesn't show first element of the list

Tags: php, arrays, yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I am js developer, but I was given a task to solve some problems in our php Yii2 site. I am novice in yii2 and php, so I am stuck with kartik yii2 widget. The code wasn't written by me. When I choose first option from the list - it saves to db correctly but shows second item in widget itself, instead of first item. When I choose all items from the list, the widget cuts first item also. But data in db is correct.

Here is the code:

```
   <?php
    ...
   function sortArray($a, $b)
   {
     return strcmp($a, $b);
   }

 $projects = ArrayHelper::map($projects, 'id', 'title');
 usort($projects, 'sortArray');
 ?>
```

```
<div class="x_title"><h3><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h3></div>

<div class="x_content">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Select2::widget([
            'name' => 'projects[]',
            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Выберите проект...'],
            'language' => 'ru',
            'value' => array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($model->projects, 'id', 'title')),
            'data' => $projects,
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ],
        ]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Обновить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
</div>
```

I check "select all" then press "update" button

[image: I check "select all" then press "update" buton]

[image: after pressing first item disappears as seen on next screen.]

[image: first item from the list is absent]

but all items were saved to db:

[image: but all items were saved to db]

How to overcome my problem and make select widget work correctly?  I am very tired. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should have to add `'maintainOrder' => true,`  for example:

```
 <?= Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'projects[]',
        'maintainOrder' => true, // add here the property
        'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Выберите проект...'],
        'language' => 'ru',
        'value' => array_keys(ArrayHelper::map($model->projects, 'id', 'title')),
        'data' => $projects,
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ],
  ]) ?>
```